# Allocation for multidimension array, partially of variable length, in C++

Tags: c++, variable-length-array

Let's say I have a multidimension array, which in C99 I could write like this:

```
#define SIZE1 10
int size2;

[...]

int myArray[SIZE1][size2];
```

Although supported by several compilers, this is not strictly C++, and won't be included until C++14.
To obtain the same (apart stack/heap problem irrelevant for my case) using boost::scoped_array, I write:

```
boost::scoped_array<int> myArray[SIZE1];
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE1; i++)
    myArray[i].reset(new int[size2]);
```

So, not so concise expression.
Am I missing something, or for multidimension arrays with variable length there is no easy plain C++ way to obtain a quick allocation?

Some reference: [Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1887097/2436175)

Comment: you want to remove all the small allocations with just one ?

Comment: @Raxvan Would it be possible? It would be already something

Comment: whel yes , but you need to handle the [] operators

Comment: Well, there is no way to get exactly this, that is to have array with lesser overhead than malloced one (for allocation and deallocation) in current C++. If you don't mind the allocation overhead, use `vector<int>` and index like this `[size1*i + j]`. (This should have the same access overhead as VLA in C)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::vector` will take both a size and an initial value, which you can use to set initial size of both the outer and inner vector:

```
vector< vector<int> > myArray(SIZE1, vector<int>(size2));
```

[`boost::multi_array`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html) is specifically designed as a multidimensional array, and is more fitting than `boost::scoped_array`.

```
boost::multi_array<int, 2> myArray(boost::extents[SIZE1][size2])
```

Comment: boost::multi_array and boost::extents, that does it, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

There is no multidimensional arrays with variable length in the C++ standard but you can easily write you own matrix class with an vector in it that calculates the vector Index by 'row_index*rowlength + column_index'.

Answer (score 0):

There is no default container for this, you need to write one **if you want only one allocation**. This is the shortest example i can give:

```
template <class T>
class Matrix
{
public:
    Matrix(const unsigned int _width,const unsigned int _height)
        :width(_width)
        ,height(_height)
    {
        elements.resize(width * height);//one allocation !
    }
    //x goes on width
    //y on height
    T&              get(const unsigned int x,const unsigned int y)
    {
        return elements[y * width + x];
    }
public:
    unsigned int    width;
    unsigned int    height;
    std::vector<T>  elements;
};

//usage:
Matrix<int> m(width_size,height_size);
m.get(10,10) = element;
```

Notice that the elements are allocated all in one vector and to find an element at `x` and `y` i used `y * width + x` to obtain the index in the vector.

Also there are already implementations for this purpose so it would be best to take one from the internet. You can check [boost library](http://www.boost.org/) for what they have there.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is a multidimensional array you could use pointers, resizing would require copying onto a new one and deleting the old, but you could do the following:

```
int** m;
int rows, cols;
cin >> rows >> cols;
m = new int* [rows];
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    m[i] = new int [cols];
}

for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    delete [] m[i];
}
delete [] m;
```

or as an alternative you could use a pointer to a 1D array such as:

```
int* m;
int rows, cols;
cin >> rows >> cols;
m = new int [rows*cols];
```

and access it by:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        m[i*cols+j] = i;
```

providing a delete statement:

```
delete [] m;
```